# keycloak to keycloak data sync

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Scenario: There are 2 instances of keycloak - let's say a `remote` instance and a `local` instance. Users should be able to authenticate using any instance. For this to happen, users data need to be synced. How to do this? Is there any other recommended way to achieve this. Cannot use LDAP.

Comment: How to create these instance ? Did you create new "realm"

Comment: @ÖmürAlçin Plan is to install keycloak on a remote server and a local server.

Comment: Hmm  if you want to synced datas you need to set same db table for remote and local keycloak.Did you try it ?

Comment: @ÖmürAlçin It is not possible because `remote` instance sits on the cloud and `local` instance should work without offline

Comment: correction: "work offline"

Comment: May be you can write a client app which using getUsers api [Keycloak  Get Users Api Doc.](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html#_get_users) .It fetches  all users from remote server and writes to local keycloak db with  scheduled time period.But you need configured your db settings before.I have shared a keycloak guide about db configuration below.

Comment: @ÖmürAlçin I was looking for out of the box solution. I will try your approach. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Your welcome.Please share your solution with us.

Answer (score 1):

Create one table for using two keycloak instances.
And set database configurations according to this table which you created.

Check here :
[Keycloak Database Configurations Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.4/server_installation/#database-configuration)

**Addition for sync problem :**
May be you can write a client app which using getUsers api [Keycloak Get Users Api Doc.](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html#_get_users)  .It fetches all users from remote server and writes to local keycloak db with scheduled time period.